# ScopeTypeVariables is Failing To Help Inference

Tags: haskell

I have little utility function for forwarding the call of type class method thru a sum type. The problem is I have to explicitly pass the constraint using Proxy. I would like to just use ScopedTypeVariables.

Here is the code

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-} 
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
module Mitsuba.Generic where
import GHC.Generics
import Data.Proxy

class GFold f c b where
    genericFold :: p c -> (forall e. c e => e -> b) -> f a -> b 

instance GFold a c d => GFold (M1 x y a) c d where
   genericFold p f (M1 x) = genericFold p f x

instance ( GFold a c d
         , GFold b c d
         ) => GFold (a :+: b) c d where
   genericFold p f = \case
      L1 x -> genericFold (Proxy :: Proxy c) f x
      R1 x -> genericFold (Proxy :: Proxy c) f x

instance c a => GFold (K1 i a) c d where
   genericFold p f (K1 x) = f x

gfold :: (Generic a, GFold (Rep a) c d) 
      => p c -> (forall e. c e => e -> d) -> a -> d
gfold p h x = genericFold p h $ from x

data Foo = I Int | D Double | B Bool
   deriving(Generic)

test :: String
test = gfold (Proxy :: Proxy Show) show $ I 1
```

So the test works like I would like it to. However, I would like the 'gfold' function to be the following.

```
gfold :: forall a c d. (Generic a, GFold (Rep a) c d) 
      => (forall e. c e => e -> d) -> a -> d
gfold h x = genericFold (Proxy :: Proxy c) h $ from x
```

Which compiles, but then the test gives the following error.

```
src/Generic.hs:39:8:
Could not deduce (c0 Bool, c0 Double, c0 Int)
  arising from a use of `gfold'
In the expression: gfold show
In the expression: gfold show $ I 1
In an equation for `test': test = gfold show $ I 1

src/Generic.hs:39:14:
Could not deduce (Show e) arising from a use of `show'
from the context (c0 e)
  bound by a type expected by the context: (c0 e) => e -> String
  at src/Mitsuba/Generic.hs:39:8-17
Possible fix:
  add (Show e) to the context of
    a type expected by the context: (c0 e) => e -> String
In the first argument of `gfold', namely `show'
In the expression: gfold show
In the expression: gfold show $ I 1
```

Is there anyway I can write the version of gfold that I want?

Comment: It's not called `-XScopedTypeLevelVariablesOfAnyKind`...

Comment: @leftaroundabout That explanation makes sense but is unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can unify `c` with `Show` in this case because `Show` is not the only possible constraint that matches `c` in `(forall e. c e => e -> d)`. It could just as well be some other type-class which implies `Show`, for example:

```
class Show a => MyShow a where
  myShow :: a -> String
  myShow a = "foo: " ++ show a

instance MyShow Int
instance MyShow Double
instance MyShow Bool
```

and now

```
test = gfold (Proxy :: Proxy MyShow) show $ I 1
```

also type-checks.

Comment: You can't unify `c` with anything, you can't even write `func = undefined :: forall c d . (forall e. c e => e -> d)`. The function passed to `gfold` must be fully polymorphic in `c` which doesn't actually make sense.

Comment: This doesn't typecheck for me with the latter version of `gfold`. Isn't the change to `gfold` meant to avoid passing the proxy parameter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if using a more explicit concrete type signature for your `gfold` function defeats the purpose of what you are trying to do, but you can make `test` typecheck with the more generic `gfold` version writing it like this:

```haskell
test :: String
test = (gfold :: ((forall e. Show e => e -> String) -> Foo -> String)) show $ I 1
```